# or-clause with date and null-values in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have following df:

```
   date_from    date_to      birth_date    death_date
0  2016-01-10   2019-06-05   2015-02-15    2018-07-25
1  2016-05-11   2020-06-13   2014-03-07    2020-07-11
2  2016-02-23   Nat          2014-03-07    2019-06-08
3  2015-12-08   Nat          2014-03-07    2019-06-08
```

I'm trying to select all cases where date_to > death_date OR where date_to = Nat.

I've tried following code:

```
df = df[(df['date_to'] > df['death_date']) | (df[df['DATE_TO'].isnull()])]
```

but I get following error-message

```
'TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]'
```

and I don't really know how to work around this problem.

Comment: You need to convert the date_from to `datetime` format

Comment: The type of all the dates is datetime64[ns] , so this is a datetime format no? Also I don't use 'date_from', I only use 'death_date' and 'date_to'

Comment: Change `(df[df['DATE_TO'].isnull()])` to `(df['DATE_TO'].isnull())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question

```
import pandas as pd
# ..... your data frame df ......

# considering that you have the following types

>>> df.dtypes
date_from     datetime64[ns]
date_to       datetime64[ns]
birth_date    datetime64[ns]
death_date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object  

df = df[(df['date_to'] > df['death_date']) | (df['date_to'].isnull())]

>>> df
date_from    date_to birth_date death_date
0 2016-01-10 2019-06-05 2015-02-15 2018-07-25
2 2016-02-23        NaT 2014-03-07 2019-06-08
3 2015-12-08        NaT 2014-03-07 2019-06-08
```

In case date_to column is not datetime you can convert like this

```
df['date_to'] = df['date_to'].replace('Nat', pd.NaT)
df['date_to'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_to'])
```